# How to keep showing data in TDBGrid after freeing the query?

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to get data from a database and fill a `TDBGrid`. When using a `try/finally` block, all records from the DataSource are cleared because I execute `Free` in the `finally`.

I have looked on Google and all examples use `q.Free` in the `finally` block.

```
procedure TSubjektiForm.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  q : TZQuery;
  ds : TDataSource;
begin
  q := TZQuery.Create(nil);
  ds := TDataSource.Create(nil);

  try
    DBGrid1.DataSource := ds;
    ds.DataSet := q;

    q.Active := False;
    q.SQL.Clear;
    q.Connection := DataModule1.ZConnection1;
    q.SQL.Text := 'SELECT id, naziv, telefon FROM subjekti';
    q.Open;
  finally
    q.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If I remove `q.Free`, the data is shown in the `TDBGrid`.

I read:

> The Finally keyword is used to mark the start of the final block of statements in a Try statement. They are executed regardless of what happens in the Try statements.

But my question is, how can I free that query? Is there any other way?

*Sorry for stupid questions, I am new to Delphi, I come from C# and this is really different!*

Comment: You should create the query from your calling code, and pass it in to this procedure, or (better yet) drop a TZQuery on your form and let the form handle freeing it when it closes. Or make the query variable a private member of the form and create it in the form's OnCreate event, and the form will free it when the form is closed. Your problem is that freeing the query closes it, which means that the data is no longer available to view. (It's not deleted, it's simply not being shown.)

Comment: So is better pratice to put component on form and than in procedure just open it? What about catching exception? Without try block program will be closed

Comment: I didn't say anything about *better practice* overall. In this specific case, you cannot free the query or datasource, or you can't display data in the DBGrid. The query and datasource have to have a lifetime outside the procedure, so what you're doing makes no sense. And `try..finally` doesn't catch exceptions - you can still do that in your form's OnCreate if you want when you open the query. I don't see any point in doing so, because if the exception is thrown when the form is being created, the default exception handler will tell the user it was a database error.

Comment: The only time you should create and free a query in a local procedure is when you're running a short-lived SQL statement (like responding to a user's button click to show the count of something). In that case, you would create the query, run the SELECT to get the count, read that value from the resultset into a variable, and close and free the query. You should read the section of the Delphi documentation about working with database applications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike in C#, objects in Delphi are not reference-counted or garbage-collected.  When you `Free()` an object in Delphi, it is gone immediately.  In C#, the equivalent is calling `Dispose()` on an object that implements `IDisposable`.

The `TDBGrid` simply displays the data that is accessible via the assigned `TDataSource`.  Your `TDataSource` is just an intermediary to connect data to the grid.  The data is not copied.  The `TZQuery` holds the actual data, so when you free that object then it and its data are gone.  That is why your grid does not display anything once the `finally` is run.

So, you need to make sure the `TZQuery` and `TDataSource` objects that you are creating will outlive the procedure that is retrieving the data.

If you are not going to drop the components onto your Form/DataModule at design-time (which you should), then at least create them in your Form/DataModule's constructor or `OnCreate` event instead.  You can assign your Form/DataModule as their `Owner` so they will be freed when the Form/DataModule is freed.

For example:

```pascal
type
  TSubjektiForm = class(TForm) // or your DataModule
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  private
    Query : TZQuery;
    ...
  end;

...

procedure TSubjektiForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ds : TDataSource;
begin
  Query := TZQuery.Create(Self);
  Query.Connection := DataModule1.ZConnection1;

  ds := TDataSource.Create(Self);
  ds.DataSet := Query;

  DBGrid1.DataSource := ds;
end;

procedure TSubjektiForm.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Query.Close;
  Query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT id, naziv, telefon FROM subjekti';
  Query.Open;
end;
```